# Creating rows after modified date

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I have multiple tables that are used to create one table every day. This table is dropped and recreated every morning.

Table A

Table B

Table C

A,B,C creates table D

I would like to create a new row each time table D is modified.

Table D

```
id   Cat  Start_dt     End_dt  
1    Sun    1/1/2019
2    Mon    1/1/2019
```

The following day the table looks like below

```
id   Cat  Start_dt       End_dt  
1    Sun    1/1/2019
2    Mon    1/1/2019    1/5/2019
```

How can I capture this modification in a new table, like below.

```
id Cat Start_dt  End_dt  Modified Date Curr_Rec Cycle_Start  Cycle_End
1  Sun 1/1/2019                           Y    1/1/2019     12/31/9999 
2  Mon 1/1/2019                                1/1/2019     1/4/2019
2  Mon 1/1/2019  1/5/2019 1/5/2019        Y    1/5/2019     12/31/9999
```

Comment: *I have multiple tables that are used to create one table every day* : is table `D` dropped and created again every day ? Or are you running `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements againts it ?

Comment: Also why do we have 3 lines in the capture table while only 2 in the original ?

Comment: How is `D` created from `A`, `B`, and `C` if now rows are wantonly added?

Comment: @GMB Table D is dropped every morning and created again. The capture table is capturing the two original records plus the row that was modified, total of three. So I want to capture the history of any change to that table.

Comment: @GMB any push to the right direction would be helpful.